# How do I increment "stat.talkedToVillager" for one villager but not another?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have two villagers, one named "Blue" and the other named "Green", and I call my two objectives for "TalkvillGreen" and "TalkvillBlue". Both scores keep count of how many villagers I have talked to.

How can I make it so that when I talk to the villager named "Green", I just get score 1 for the objective "TalkvillGreen" and not "TalkvillBlue"?

Comment: Do you need the villagers to have any trades, or are they just there to right click? I'm thinking of using the fact that `Offers` only generates when the villager is traded with to detect which villager was traded with (then incrementing the blue/green score of players who have stat.talkedToVillager >= 1).

Comment: They are just there to right click. That may work i think, if you could give me some commands, i could work with, then that would be great.

Comment: Started writing something, but I can't find a way to remove the `Offers` compound tag so that it can be generated again to detect another interaction. Would it be plausible to re-summon the villager each interaction? (You can teleport the old one to the void so it looks seamless)

Comment: Go to this web site: https://mcstacker.bimbimma.com/

Comment: This web site will help you make an villager without trades

Comment: I know how to summon a villager without an `Offers` tag, what I don't know how to do (or if it's possible) is removing the `Offers` tag  from an already-generated villager. Is it plausible in your situation to re-summon the villager after each interaction? (It can look seamless, just means that the villager will lose any scores you've put on it)

Comment: Yea that fine for me

Comment: The score i want to set back to 0 again afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a lot more commands than I was originally predicting, but the following should work.

First, you'll need 3 objectives for this. The first two you've already set up, but with a different type:

```
/scoreboard objectives add TalkVillBlue dummy
/scoreboard objectives add TalkVillGreen dummy
/scoreboard objectives add TalkVill stat.talkedToVillager
```

Then, on a clock, run the following commands in this order:

```
/scoreboard players tag @e[type=Villager,name=Green] add VillTalkedTo {Offers:{}}
/scoreboard players tag @e[type=Villager,name=Blue] add VillTalkedTo {Offers:{}}
/execute @e[tag=VillTalkedTo,name=Green] ~ ~ ~ /scoreboard players add @p[score_TalkVill_min=1] TalkVillGreen 1
/execute @e[tag=VillTalkedTo,name=Blue] ~ ~ ~ /scoreboard players add @p[score_TalkVill_min=1] TalkVillBlue 1
/execute @e[tag=VillTalkedTo,name=Green] ~ ~ ~ /summon Villager ~ ~ ~ {Tags:[NewVill],CustomName:"Green"}
/execute @e[tag=VillTalkedTo,name=Blue] ~ ~ ~ /summon Villager ~ ~ ~ {Tags:[NewVill],CustomName:"Blue"}
/execute @e[tag=VillTalkedTo] ~ ~ ~ /teleport @e[tag=NewVill,c=1] ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
/tp @e[tag=VillTalkedTo] ~ -500 ~
/kill @e[tag=VillTalkedTo]
/scoreboard players tag @e[tag=VillTalkedTo] remove VillTalkedTo
/scoreboard players set @a[score_TalkVill_min=1] TalkVill 0
```

What this does is:

1&2. Tag any villagers that have been traded with (and thus their `Offers` tag generated) with `VillTalkedTo`
3&4. Makes any talked to villagers increment the player who just interacted with them's `TalkVillGreen` or `TalkVillBlue` score
5&6. Resummon themselves (as they're about to die), this is where you'll need to put any tags specific to these villagers if you have any other than their name
7. Teleport the newly summoned villager to themself, in order to have it rotated correctly
8&9. Teleport the talked to green/blue villagers into the void, then kill them
10&11. Reset the tags and scores used, ready to detect again

Comment: But then I dont need stat.talkedtovillager for the first and second scoreboards ?

Comment: @MaxFox Nope, they're incremented by the commands when they need to be

Comment: Cool, got to just try this

Comment: Should I have the green and the blue commands in separate rows.

Comment: @MaxFox It should all works as one long chain

Comment: Ok, but should the first command block be a repeater, then the rest chain.

Comment: @MaxFox Yep, make sure none of them are conditional, and all of them are `Always Active`

Comment: When you mean tags, do you mean this: /summon Villager ~ ~1 ~ {CustomName:"Green",CustomNameVisible:1,Tags:["Green"],NoGravity:1b,Profession:0,Invulnerable:1,NoAI:1,Silent:1} Or This Tags:["Green"]

Comment: @MaxFox The first one. You should be able to add the tags like you have there.

Comment: On the villtalkedto, should i have Green an Blue as tags ? Or should it be a diffrent name like instead of Green, maybe green

Comment: @MaxFox Green and Blue as their custom names should be all that's needed.

Comment: Ok but i want Blue And green to teleport to separate places so then i need two of these commands (/teleport @e[tag=NewVill,c=1] ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ) and whould need two diffrent NewVill LIke NewVillGreen and NewVillBlue, but i dont know how you think about this.

Comment: Its fine now i got it working.

Comment: @Skylinerw I have one problem i didnt want to trade with them, and that offers to come up when i clicked on the villager, but it works thats good.